# How can I make the type emoji or type anything

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am currently working on a custom keyboard 
and I encountered a problem when I try to combine the textDocumentProxy in a new window

So have add emoji keyboard button
  and which I pass page with the addition of two buttons of emoji Now my problem is how I can incorporate textDocumentProxy another window or link between them waned even can type emoji

**I try to type anything not only emoji**

Full source code is here

https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard

```
import UIKit

class DefaultSettings1: ExtraView, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView1: UITableView?
    @IBOutlet var effectsView: UIVisualEffectView?
    @IBOutlet var backButton1: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet var settingsLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var pixelLine: UIView?
    @IBOutlet var keyPressed: UIButton?



    override var darkMode: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.updateAppearance(darkMode)
        }
    }

    let cellBackgroundColorDark = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(CGFloat(0.25))
    let cellBackgroundColorLight = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(CGFloat(1))
    let cellLabelColorDark = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let cellLabelColorLight = UIColor.blackColor()
    let cellLongLabelColorDark = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    let cellLongLabelColorLight = UIColor.grayColor()

    // TODO: these probably don't belong here, and also need to be localized
      required init(globalColors: GlobalColors.Type?, darkMode: Bool, solidColorMode: Bool) {
        super.init(globalColors: globalColors, darkMode: darkMode, solidColorMode: solidColorMode)
        self.loadNib()
    }



    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("loading from nib not supported")
    }

    func loadNib() {
        let assets = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).loadNibNamed("DefaultSettings1", owner: self, options: nil)

        if assets.count > 0 {
            if var rootView = assets.first as? UIView {
                rootView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                self.addSubview(rootView)

                let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rootView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rootView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rootView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rootView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

                self.addConstraint(left)
                self.addConstraint(right)
                self.addConstraint(top)
                self.addConstraint(bottom)
            }
        }

        self.tableView1?.registerClass(DefaultSettings1TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.tableView1?.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
        self.tableView1?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

        // XXX: this is here b/c a totally transparent background does not support scrolling in blank areas
        self.tableView1?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.01)

        self.updateAppearance(self.darkMode)
    }



    func tableView1(tableView1: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if var cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? DefaultSettings1TableViewCell {

            if cell.sw.allTargets().count == 0 {
                cell.sw.addTarget(self, action: Selector("toggleSetting1:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            }



            cell.backgroundColor = (self.darkMode ? cellBackgroundColorDark : cellBackgroundColorLight)
            cell.label.textColor = (self.darkMode ? cellLabelColorDark : cellLabelColorLight)
            cell.longLabel.textColor = (self.darkMode ? cellLongLabelColorDark : cellLongLabelColorLight)

            cell.changeConstraints()

            return cell
        }
        else {
            assert(false, "this is a bad thing that just happened")
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }




    func updateAppearance(dark: Bool) {
        if dark {
            self.effectsView?.effect
            let blueColor = UIColor(red: 135/CGFloat(255), green: 206/CGFloat(255), blue: 250/CGFloat(255), alpha: 1)
            self.pixelLine?.backgroundColor = blueColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(CGFloat(0.5))
            self.backButton1?.setTitleColor(blueColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.settingsLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

            if let visibleCells = self.tableView1?.visibleCells() {
                for cell in visibleCells {
                    if var cell = cell as? UITableViewCell {
                        cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColorDark
                        var label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
                        label?.textColor = cellLabelColorDark
                        var longLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UITextView
                        longLabel?.textColor = cellLongLabelColorDark
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            let blueColor = UIColor(red: 0/CGFloat(255), green: 122/CGFloat(255), blue: 255/CGFloat(255), alpha: 1)
            self.pixelLine?.backgroundColor = blueColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(CGFloat(0.5))
            self.backButton1?.setTitleColor(blueColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.settingsLabel?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

            if let visibleCells = self.tableView1?.visibleCells() {
                for cell in visibleCells {
                    if var cell = cell as? UITableViewCell {
                        cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColorLight
                        var label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
                        label?.textColor = cellLabelColorLight
                        var longLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UITextView
                        longLabel?.textColor = cellLongLabelColorLight
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }

class DefaultSettings1TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
       var sw: UISwitch
    var label: UILabel
    var longLabel: UITextView
    var constraintsSetForLongLabel: Bool
    var cellConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        self.sw = UISwitch()
        self.label = UILabel()
        self.longLabel = UITextView()
        self.cellConstraints = []

        self.constraintsSetForLongLabel = false

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.sw.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.longLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        self.longLabel.text = nil
        self.longLabel.scrollEnabled = false
        self.longLabel.selectable = false
        self.longLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        self.sw.tag = 1
        self.label.tag = 2
        self.longLabel.tag = 3

        self.addSubview(self.sw)
        self.addSubview(self.label)
        self.addSubview(self.longLabel)

        self.addConstraints()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addConstraints() {
        let margin: CGFloat = 8
        let sideMargin = margin * 2

        let hasLongText = self.longLabel.text != nil && !self.longLabel.text.isEmpty
        if hasLongText {
            let switchSide = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -sideMargin)
            let switchTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)
            let labelSide = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: sideMargin)
            let labelCenter = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            self.addConstraint(switchSide)
            self.addConstraint(switchTop)
            self.addConstraint(labelSide)
            self.addConstraint(labelCenter)

            let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: longLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: sideMargin)
            let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: longLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -sideMargin)
            let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: longLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)
            let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: longLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -margin)

            self.addConstraint(left)
            self.addConstraint(right)
            self.addConstraint(top)
            self.addConstraint(bottom)

            self.cellConstraints += [switchSide, switchTop, labelSide, labelCenter, left, right, top, bottom]

            self.constraintsSetForLongLabel = true
        }
        else {
            let switchSide = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -sideMargin)
            let switchTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)
            let switchBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -margin)
            let labelSide = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: sideMargin)
            let labelCenter = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: sw, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            self.addConstraint(switchSide)
            self.addConstraint(switchTop)
            self.addConstraint(switchBottom)
            self.addConstraint(labelSide)
            self.addConstraint(labelCenter)

            self.cellConstraints += [switchSide, switchTop, switchBottom, labelSide, labelCenter]

            self.constraintsSetForLongLabel = false
        }
    }

    // XXX: not in updateConstraints because it doesn't play nice with UITableViewAutomaticDimension for some reason
    func changeConstraints() {
        let hasLongText = self.longLabel.text != nil && !self.longLabel.text.isEmpty
        if hasLongText != self.constraintsSetForLongLabel {
            self.removeConstraints(self.cellConstraints)
            self.cellConstraints.removeAll()
            self.addConstraints()
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: So you want to unable emoji buttons from setting view in your custom keyboard?

Comment: yes pleasse can you hellp me? Excuse me may not explain myself well, but I'm happy to send you the source code then how might understand me better

Comment: Yes sure you can store the changes onto `NSUserDefaults` when user enable emoji buttons.

Comment: I sent you a thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change many things into your project as per your requirement like you can use that setting view by hiding that tableView and add one UIView on it after that you can add emojis into that view and when user click on setting button from keyboard you can hide your emojis view and show tableview but when user want to type smiles that you don't need to hide anything just show your emojis view.

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00216679687463922141) is your updated project.